# Css font face doesn't work in IE

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I am using some fonts generated from FontSquirrel but it doesn't seem to that IE can't handle the fonts.. What am I doing wrong? This is not a public webpage.. It is builded to work on a local platform until I am ready to launch, that's why the domain name ends on `.local`.

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima_light';
    src: url('http://www.anotherdomain.local/fonts/proximanova-light-webfont.eot');
    src: local('proxima_light'), url('http://www.anotherdomain.local/fonts/proximanova-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://www.anotherdomain.local/fonts/proximanova-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://www.anotherdomain.local/fonts/proximanova-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://www.anotherdomain.local/fonts/proximanova-light-webfont.svg#proxima_nova_ltregular') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
 }

 @font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima';
    src: url('http://www.anotherdomain.local/fonts/proximanova-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: local('proxima'), url('http://www.anotherdomain.local/fonts/proximanova-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://www.anotherdomain.local/fonts/proximanova-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://www.anotherdomain.local/fonts/proximanova-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://www.anotherdomain.local/fonts/proximanova-regular-webfont.svg#proxima_nova_rgregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
 }

 @font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima';
    src: url('http://www.anotherdomain.local/fonts/proximanova-semibold-webfont.eot');
    src: local('proxima'), url('http://www.anotherdomain.local/fonts/proximanova-semibold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://www.anotherdomain.local/fonts/proximanova-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://www.anotherdomain.local/fonts/proximanova-semibold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://www.anotherdomain.local/fonts/proximanova-semibold-webfont.svg#proxima_nova_ltbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-style: normal;
 }
```

As I said.. it is only IE that doesn't handle the font-face.. Every other browser does it well..

Comment: The last two `font-face` have the same name ( `'font-family:proxima'` ).

Comment: Just as a blind guess without checking your code further - is there any log output concerning the resources? Might be that IE is very restrictive on the same origin thingy when browsing local websites.

Comment: @MichaelRose I could image that.. Also the reason for why I pointed out the `.local`.. But still.. I don't know how to fix it..

Comment: @Vucko Yeah.. But it is different `font-weight` which should be enough to indicate the difference..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this'll help, but IE has some similar cross-domain issues as FF.  In this case, it might be that your absolute URL is making IE think your font is being served from a different domain.  Have you tried using a relative path?

Answer (score 0):

Does Dev Console return error on laod the font files, also could you please provide of the Responce Header of the font file.
I've faced with issue in IE 9 when it didn't use font file in case if Responce header contained **Cache-Control: no-cache**